# Implement matplotlib concise date formatter without weekends

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot data that should exclude weekends. Using code from [matplotlib examples](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_index_formatter2.html) works for the proper formatting to exclude weekends, but loses all of the pretty formatting of the Concise Date Formatter. Does anyone know of any clever ways of getting Concise Date Formatter to work without weekends (or with integers which index a list of dates)

```
import dateutil.parser
from matplotlib import cbook, dates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import Formatter
import numpy as np


datafile = cbook.get_sample_data('msft.csv', asfileobj=False)
print('loading %s' % datafile)
msft_data = np.genfromtxt(
datafile, delimiter=',', names=True,
converters={0: lambda s: dates.date2num(dateutil.parser.parse(s))})


class MyFormatter(Formatter):
    def __init__(self, dates, fmt='%Y-%m-%d'):
        self.dates = dates
        self.fmt = fmt

    def __call__(self, x, pos=0):
        """Return the label for time x at position pos."""
        ind = int(round(x))
        if ind >= len(self.dates) or ind < 0:
            return ''
        return dates.num2date(self.dates[ind]).strftime(self.fmt)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(MyFormatter(msft_data['Date']))
ax.plot(msft_data['Close'], 'o-')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this sample is to create a graph by converting date and time data into numbers in the format handled by matplotlib and then back again. Saturdays and Sundays are not relevant. The same data was used to create the graph.

```
from matplotlib import cbook, dates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

datafile = cbook.get_sample_data('msft.csv', asfileobj=False)
df = pd.read_csv(datafile, sep=',')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%b-%y')
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = df['Close'].plot(kind='line', style='o-')
ax.invert_xaxis()
#update
locator = dates.AutoDateLocator()
formatter = dates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.show()
```

[image]

mplfinance liblary use

```
import yfinance as yf
import mplfinance as mpf
import pandas as pd

df = yf.download("AAPL", start="2021-01-01", end="2021-03-01")
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

mpf.plot(df[1:10], figratio=(8,4), type='line', volume=False, style='classic', xrotation=0)
```

[image]

Comment: in your first iteration of the code, you should pass the `ax` object that you create with `plt.subplots` to `df.plot`

Comment: Thanks for the sample. This works to remove the weekends, but you still lose the formatting from concise date formatter

Comment: What is your definition of a concise date formatter?

Comment: Is this the concise date formatter you are expecting?

Comment: yes exactly, but that will have empty weekends (it's just hard to see give the date range). If you reduce to the first 10 elements you'll see a gap like here: https://imgur.com/a/5vhRio0

Comment: I checked the image. Is it in a state that does not include data for Saturday and Sunday? What happens if I change the date to a string?

Comment: Correct, this is financial data where there is not data on weekends (saturday+sunday). I believe changing the date to a string will make the concise date formatter no longer work

Comment: `lables = [19,17,15,11,9];ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(labels))`I don't think there is any way to control the AutoDateLocator, so you can set your own preferred xticklabels and use FixedFormatter() to set them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229988/discussion-between-vasseurth-and-r-beginners).

Comment: One of the most famous visualizations of investment data is [mplfinence](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance). This can be used to support market holidays and various other visualizations. The graph shows 1/9 and 1/10 are closed days. For your reference

Comment: It's all about customization after all. It's a choice between expression and efficiency. If you want to invest, I recommend mplfinance. If my answer was helpful to you, please accept it as a correct answer and give it a 1+!